# Convergence of sequence of function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\{ f_n \}$ be a sequence of continuous complex-valued functions on $R$ such that $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty } f_n(x)$ exists (as a complex number) for each $x \in R$, and let $\epsilon > 0$.

Prove that there is a non-empty open subset $V$ of $R$ and a positive integer $N$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x) | \leq \epsilon $ if $x \in V$ and $n \geq N$.

---

I am a little confuse on this questions. It seems like what the question asked me to prove is just from the definition that $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty } f_n(x)$.

If you can offer me some guidelines I would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question asks you to prove that there is a non-empty open set such that the convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ satisfies a condition similar to that of uniform convergence there. This is different from the pointwise convergence of $f_n$ to $f$: that $f_n \to f$ pointwise on $\mathbf R$ means that for every $x \in \mathbf R$ and every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an integer $N$ - depending on $x$ and on $\epsilon$ - such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \le \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$. A different $x$ may require a larger $N$. You are asked to show that there is a non-empty open set on which the choice of $N$ is independent of $x$.

I have managed to prove the statement by an application of the Baire category theorem, **under the additional assumption that the limit function $f$ is continuous also**.

I will assume acquaintance with the following (there is an abundance of resources on this topic):

- The definition of a nowhere dense set.
- The Baire category theorem: a non-empty complete metric space is not a countable union of nowhere dense sets.
- A closed subset of a metric space is nowhere dense if and only if it has empty interior.

As for the proof (assuming continuity of $f$!):

1. Explain why we can assume, without loss of generality, that each $f_n$ is real-valued and that $f = 0$.

Suppose now that $\{ f_n \}$ is a sequence of continuous real functions on $\mathbf R$ converging pointwise to $0$, and let $\epsilon > 0$.

2. Why is the set $f_n^{-1} \big( [-\epsilon, \epsilon] \big)$ closed for all $n$?

Define a sequence $\{ A_k \}_{k \in \mathbf N}$ of subsets of $\mathbf R$ by
$$A_k = \bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty} f_n^{-1} \big( [-\epsilon, \epsilon] \big).$$

3. Why is each $A_k$ closed in $\mathbf R$?
4. Explain why we have
   $$\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k = \mathbf R.$$

Since $\mathbf R$ is complete, it follows from $(4)$ and the Baire category theorem that at least one $A_k$ is *not* nowhere dense, i.e., there is an $N \in \mathbf N$ such that $A_N$ is not nowhere dense.

5. Explain why $A_N$ contains a non-empty open set $V$.

If $x$ is any point of $V$, then $x$ also lies in $A_N$, and therefore in $f_n^{-1} \big( [-\epsilon, \epsilon] \big)$ for every $n \ge N$.

6. Explain why the proof is finished.

**Edit**

- The completeness of $\mathbf R$ is now explicitly mentioned.
- Added the assumption in $(1)$ that each $f_n$ is real-valued.
- Reformulated the first paragraph stating what are are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is a very good answer. I really like how you walk me through the solution step by step. Thank you. I think the assumption of f is continuous is okay right? because $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly then $f$ must a continuous function.

Comment: @user209663 I have updated the answer - we are not trying to prove uniform convergence on some open set. The open set $V$ depends on $\epsilon$, and there is no guarantee that what remains is an open set when $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: To get rid of the assumption that $f$ is continuous, consider $D_{n,k} = \{ x : \lvert f_n(x) - f_k(x)\rvert \leqslant \varepsilon\}$. By continuity of the $f_n$, that's a closed set. Then let $$F_n = \bigcap_{k = n+1}^{\infty} D_{n,k}.$$ The pointwise convergence implies $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup F_n$, so some $F_n$ has nonempty interior by Baire.